# NodeJS - passar uma função em formato de promises para async await

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tenho o código de uma aplicação feita há um tempo atrás, porém foi feita usando promises, then/catch, estou tentando me familiarizar com o async await mas estou tendo dificuldades,Gostaria de ver como ficaria este código em forma de async await. segue o código(ps: estou usando mongoose):

```
const productsModel = require("../models/ProductsModel");

exports.getDashboard = (req, res, next) => {
    let category = req.query.category;
    let validCategories = ["Computadores", "Joysticks", "Monitores"];
    let productsPromise;
    if (category && validCategories.includes(category))
        productsPromise = productsModel.getProductsByCategoria(category);
    else productsPromise = productsModel.getAllProducts();
    productsPromise
        .then(products => {
            res.render("inicio", {
                products: products,
                isUser: req.session.userId,
                isAdm: req.session.isAdm,
                validationError: req.flash("validationErrors")[0],
                pageTitle: "Dashboard"
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};
```

Comment: Não sei se isso faz parte do escopo do site, mas você pode ver um exemplo [aqui](https://pastebin.com/yFNJp9Y9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, bom dia, segue por gentileza uma possível solução...

```
exports.getDashboard = async(req, res, next) => {
  const category = req.query.category;
  const validCategories = ["Computadores", "Joysticks", "Monitores"];
  const hasCategory = category && validCategories.includes(category);   
  const {isUser, isAdmin} = req.sessions;
   
 try {

    const products = hasCategory ? 
       await productsModel.getProductsByCategoria(category) :
       await productsModel.getAllProducts();
 
   res.render({
            products,
            isUser,
            isAdmin,
            validationError: req.flash("validationErrors")[0], 
            pageTitle: "Dashboard"
       });

   }catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
   }
}
```